# How to cudaMemcpy a __device__ initialized var

Tags: c++, pointers, cuda

I have some working code... where I allocate a device variable pointer as follows:

```
float *d_var;
cudaMalloc(&d_var, sizeof(float) );
```

Later on in my code, I want to copy the contents of this var to a local var (ref):

```
checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(&h_var, &d_var, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
```

Which works great! But using `cudaMalloc` is **slow**!

---

So I want to instead allocate the variable without using `cudaMalloc` using a `__device__` definition:

```
__device__ float d_var = 1000000000.0f;
```

This works great and I know the d_var in this case is initialized properly and I can do all my work with it like before. I've been printf'ing its contents, so I know it has the right contents. But when I try to copy the contents now to my host var using the same code as before:

```
checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(&h_var, &d_var, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
```

I get a really vague error:

```
invalid argument cudaMemcpy(&h_var, &d_var, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost)
```

I've tried referring to the variable as `&d_var`, `d_var`, `*d_var` to no avail.
Any help MUCH appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bah, I figured it out....
Instead of calling `cudaMemcpy();` I need to use `cudaMemcpyFromSymbol();`

```
checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_var, d_var, sizeof(float), 0, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
```